# Process Line layout issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to build one page from my layout but I have some hard time. I have to create a Process line as shown on the picture. I am trying also to make it responsive but i have the feeling that my code is very messy.

[image]

```css
.process-steps h2 { font-family: "Rubik-Regular", sans-serif; font-size: 40px; color: #1e1e22; margin: 55px 0 70px 0; }
.process-steps .green-span { font-family: "Rubik-Bold", sans-serif; color: #23b58a; }

.actual-graph { position: relative; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; }
.actual-graph h4 { font-family: "Rubik-Medium", sans-serif; font-size: 18px; color: #2a2a2e; line-height: 28px;  }
.actual-graph p { font-family: "Rubik-Regular", sans-serif; font-size: 16px; color: #46464c; line-height: 22px; } 
.step-1 { position: absolute; width: 25%; right: 86%; bottom: 0; left: 0; top: 42%; }
.step-2 { position: absolute; width: 25%; left: 13%; bottom: 0; right: 0; top: -7.8%; }
.step-3 { position: absolute; width: 25%; left: 37.5%; bottom: 0; right: 0; top: 42%; }
.step-4 { position: absolute; width: 25%; left: 61%; bottom: 0; right: 0;  top: -7.8%; }
.step-5 { position: absolute; width: 25%; left: 85%; bottom: 0; right: 0; top: 42%; }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<section class="process-steps">
  <div class="container">
    <h2><span class="green-span">5 Steps</span> Process</h2>
    <div class="graph-container">
      <div class="actual-graph">
        <img src="https://s17.postimg.org/bhxksjwkf/graph.png" width="1171" height="191" title="someText" alt="someText" class="img-responsive">
        <div class="step-1">
          <h4>Create your account</h4>
          <p>The process begins when you
            <br>create an account with Sellr.</p>
        </div>
        <!-- step-1 -->
        <div class="step-2">
          <h4>Select Store Picks</h4>
          <p>Select 20-30 products from
            <br>each product category that you
            <br>want to promote.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="step-3">
          <h4>Wait for processing</h4>
          <p>We ensure high quality
            <br>information on your store picks
            <br>in 7-10 business days.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="step-4">
          <h4>Install Sellr Tablets</h4>
          <p>Place Sellr tablets throughout
            <br>your store.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="step-5">
          <h4>Start increasing sales!</h4>
          <p>Your store is now equipped to
            <br>start increasing sales for your
            <br>selected products.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- container -->
</section>
<!-- process-steps -->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

[https://codepen.io/sheetalsinghwd/pen/LYYMOam]

```
var canvas, ctx, p = function (x,y) {
    return { x:x, y:y };
};

// drawing
$(function() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.canvas.width  = window.innerWidth;
    ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

    ctx.lineCap = 'round';
    ctx.lineWidth = 4;

    ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(50,30,120,0.5)';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.wavy(p(80, 120), p(650, 120), 2, 12, 4);

    ctx.stroke();


});



CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.wavy = function(from, to, frequency, amplitude, step, negative) 
{ 
    var cx = 0, cy = 0, 
        fx = from.x, fy = from.y, 
        tx = to.x, ty = to.y,
        i = 0, waveOffsetLength = 0,

        ang = Math.atan2(ty - fy, tx - fx),
        distance = Math.sqrt((fx - tx) * (fx - tx) + (fy - ty) * (fy - ty)),
        a = amplitude * (!negative ? 1 : -1),
        f = Math.PI * frequency;

    for (i; i <= distance; i += step) 
    {
        waveOffsetLength = Math.sin((i / distance) * f) * a;
        cx = from.x + Math.cos(ang) * i + Math.cos(ang - Math.PI/2) * waveOffsetLength;
        cy = from.y + Math.sin(ang) * i + Math.sin(ang - Math.PI/2) * waveOffsetLength;
        i > 0 ? this.lineTo(cx, cy) : this.moveTo(cx, cy);
    }
}
```

use this for canvas

you can refer to this link.. even i am working on that.. i have just tried to create wavy lines through css and javascript`